# Nested SSH using Python Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, nested, paramiko

I have this scenario:

Local-host --------- jump-host ------- target-machine

I am trying to write a code in Python using Paramiko to first SSH from local-host to jump-host and then SSH from jump-host to the target-machine.
From the target-machine, I want to capture some outputs and store them locally either as a variable or as a file (haven't got to that point yet).
I found an example from Stack Overflow where they talk about using nested SSH with Paramiko, and I follow it but I get stuck here:

My code:

```
enter code here

#!/usr/bin/python
#
# Paramiko
#
import paramiko
import sys
import subprocess
#
# we instantiate a new object referencing paramiko's SSHClient class
#
vm=paramiko.SSHClient()
vm.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
vm.connect('192.168.115.103',username='osmanl',password='xxxxxx')
#
vmtransport = vm.get_transport()
dest_addr = ('192.168.115.103', 22)
local_addr = ('127.0.0.1', 22)
vmchannel = vmtransport.open_channel("direct-tcpip", dest_addr, local_addr)
#
jhost=paramiko.SSHClient()
jhost.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
jhost.load_host_keys('/home/osmanl/.ssh/known_hosts')
jhost.connect('10.103.53.26', username='latiu', password='xxxx', sock=vmchannel)
#
stdin, stdout, stderr = rtr.exec_command("show version | no-more")
#
print stdout.readline()
#
jhost.close()
vm.close()
# End
```

---

When I run the above, I get this error:

```
$ python sshvm.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sshvm.py", line 28, in <module>
    jhost.load_host_keys('/home/osmanl/.ssh/known_hosts')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko-1.15.2-py2.7.egg/paramiko/client.py", line 121, in load_host_keys
    self._host_keys.load(filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko-1.15.2-py2.7.egg/paramiko/hostkeys.py", line 94, in load
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/osmanl/.ssh/known_hosts'
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try the following edited code, it should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#
# Paramiko
#
import paramiko
#
# we instantiate a new object referencing paramiko's SSHClient class
#
vm = paramiko.SSHClient()
vm.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
vm.connect('192.168.115.103', username='osmanl', password='xxxxxx')
#
vmtransport = vm.get_transport()
dest_addr = ('10.103.53.26', 22) #edited#
local_addr = ('192.168.115.103', 22) #edited#
vmchannel = vmtransport.open_channel("direct-tcpip", dest_addr, local_addr)
#
jhost = paramiko.SSHClient()
jhost.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
#jhost.load_host_keys('/home/osmanl/.ssh/known_hosts') #disabled#
jhost.connect('10.103.53.26', username='latiu', password='xxxx', sock=vmchannel)
#
stdin, stdout, stderr = jhost.exec_command("show version | no-more") #edited#
#
print stdout.read() #edited#
#
jhost.close()
vm.close()
# End
```

Comment: To shed some light on all the addresses and ports in the code: 1) `local_addr` should be  local IP and port. Not server A's IP and port. But actually, the value is not really used. For example, PuTTY when doing port forwarding passes `'0.0.0.0'` and `0` there. 2) The `'10.103.53.26'` in the `jhost.connect` is not really used either. It's probably only used for host key verification, what this code explicitly skips by using `AutoAddPolicy` (what is wrong – for a correct solution, use  For a correct solution, see [Paramiko “Unknown Server”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883)).

Answer (score 6):

I know OP has specifically asked for `Paramiko` but i can do this very easily with [`fabric`](http://docs.fabfile.org/). Here is my solution

```
from fabric import Connection

out = Connection('host1').run('host2 uptime')
print(out.stdout.strip())
```

This works just fine for me, and i have the output stored in a variable as well.

Comment: After an hour or so spent on other solutions, I got this working in just minutes. Great recommendation!

Comment: How do you setup the gateway/jump host, as in the question, when using fabric?

Answer (score 2):

I found this easiest route to login to remote server via jumphost.This works amazing!

```
    link :https://pypi.org/project/jumpssh/
    import jumpssh
```

Answer (score 2):

After reading accepted answer got bit confused about source and destintation addresses https://stackoverflow.com/a/36096801/1303321, so refering to https://www.programcreek.com/python/?code=grycap%2Fim%2Fim-master%2FIM%2FSSH.py
here is what I ended up with working solution:

```
def __run_remote_command(self, command: str) -> Tuple[str, str]:
        """
        Private method to run a command in the remote machine via SSH.
        This method establishes the connection; fires the command; collects the output then closes the connection
        :param command: command which needs to be invoked in the remote machine
        :return (stdout, stderr) : Tuple of string containing the standard output and error of the command execution
        """
        stdout, stderr = '', ''
        with paramiko.SSHClient() as jhost:
            jhost.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            private_key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(filename=RESOURCES_SERVER_SSH_KEY)
            try:
                jhost.connect(hostname=JUMPHOST_SERVER_URL, username=RESOURCES_SERVER_SSH_USERNAME, pkey=private_key)
                jhost_transport = jhost.get_transport()
                dest_addr = (RESOURCES_SERVER_URL, 22)
                local_addr = (JUMPHOST_SERVER_URL, 22)
                jhost_channel = jhost_transport.open_channel("direct-tcpip", dest_addr, local_addr)

                with paramiko.SSHClient() as target_server:
                    target_server.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
                    target_server_private_key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(filename=RESOURCES_SERVER_SSH_KEY)
                    target_server.connect(hostname=RESOURCES_SERVER_URL, username=RESOURCES_SERVER_SSH_USERNAME, pkey=target_server_private_key, sock=jhost_channel)

                    self.logger.info(f"Invoking {command} on remote host {RESOURCES_SERVER_URL} over SSH")
                    _, stdout, stderr = target_server.exec_command(command)
                    stdout = stdout.read().decode('utf-8')
                    stderr = stderr.read().decode('utf-8')
            except SSHException as ssh_ex:
                self.logger.error(f"Failed to connect to {RESOURCES_SERVER_URL} ")
                self.logger.exception(ssh_ex, exc_info=True)
                raise BaseException()
        return (stdout, stderr)
```

Comment: Thank you for providing the script. I appreciate it. Question, I receive `Exception: SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner` exception. Did you encounter it? If yes how did you solve? I already tried to increase `banner_timeout` but no success.

Comment: @DataBach: No, I didn't encounter such an exception ever AFAIR. This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25609153/paramiko-error-reading-ssh-protocol-banner.