# Connecting to a server via another server using Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I am trying to get into a server using Paramiko and then get into a router that's in the server and then run a command.

However, I am not getting a password input for the router and then it just closes the connection.

```
username, password, port = ...
router = ...
hostname = ...
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.WarningPolicy)
client.connect(hostname, port = port, username = username, password = password)

cmd = # ssh hostname@router

# password input comes out here but gets disconnected

stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(cmd) 

HERE # command to run in the router
stdout.read()

client.close()
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you better use port forwarding (aka SSH tunnel) to connect to a server via another server.

See [Nested SSH using Python Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35304525/850848).

---

Anyway to answer your literal question:

1. OpenSSH `ssh` needs terminal when prompting for a password, so you would need to set `get_pty` parameter of [`SSHClient.exec_command`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.exec_command) (that can get you lot of nasty side effects).
2. Then you need to write the password to the command (`ssh`) input.
3. And then you need to write the (sub)commands to the `ssh` input.
   See [Execute (sub)commands in secondary shell/command on SSH server in Python Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58452390/850848).

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(cmd, get_pty=True) 
stdin.write('password\n')
stdin.flush()
stdin.write('subcommand\n')
stdin.flush()
```

*But this approach is error prone in general.*