# Nested SSH into server then into a router using Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, router, paramiko

My goal is to connect to a server using ssh and then ssh again into a router in that server using `paramiko`.

This is what I have tried.

```
username, password, port = credentials...
hostname = 1st server
router = router server
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.WarningPolicy)
client.connect(hostname, port = port, username = username, password = password)
print("connecting to {} from {} as {}".format(router, hostname, username))
# Calls syslog.py from the server
cmd = "ssh {}@{}".format('root', router)
print('command = {}'.format(cmd))
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(cmd, get_pty = True)
stdin.write(pw here)
stdin.flush()
stdin.write('show ?\n')
stdin.flush()

client.close()
```

I am connecting into the server and then the router and run `show ?` in the router.

`show ?` is supposed to give me a list of all possible commands starting with `show`. However, when I run the script, it gives me

```
connecting to <router ip> from <1st server> as root
command = ssh root@<router ip>
```

and then it just ends without showing the result of `show ?`

It's really hard to catch the issue because it doesn't show an error.

Any help please?

Comment: Might be helpful: https://gist.github.com/tintoy/443c42ea3865680cd624039c4bb46219

Comment: I tried to use it, but for any command in the router, it gives me `b"% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.\r"`

Comment: You are not reading the command output. See [Paramiko: read from standard output of remotely executed command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17137859/850848).

Comment: Not to mention that running `ssh` on the jump server is rather a hack. You better use a port forwarding, as I have suggested you already: [Connecting to a server via another server using Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57210100/850848).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I've tried, but the credentials didn't work for some reason. This is the command that I used to run that: `python forward.py -p 22 -u <name of 1st server> -P <pw for the router> -r <router ip>` then I typed the password for the 1st server in the following `Enter SSH password:` input

Comment: It should be `python forward.py -p random_port -u jumpserver_username -r router_ip:router_port jumpserver_ip` and then `ssh -P random_port router_username@127.0.0.1`

Comment: @MartinPrikryl is jumpserver the first server?

Comment: Yes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jump_server

Comment: When I connect to the router using terminal, I usually just do root@<router_ip> and do not type the port number. Any idea on how to get that?

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Comment: Actually, nevermind. I am now using this command: `python forward.py -p 22 -u <server_username> -r <router_ip:port> <server_ip> ssh -P 22 <router_username>@127.0.0.1` this gives me `Usage: forward.py [options] <ssh-server>[:<server-port>]` And without the `ssh` followed in the command, it gives me, `*** Failed to connect to 173.36.240.172:22: NoValidConnectionsError(None, 'Unable to connect to port 22 on <server_ip>')`

Comment: So can you connect to `173.36.240.172:22` from the machine where run that?

Comment: No. When I connect to the first server from my local machine, I just do `ssh root@<server_name>` I don't type the IP or port.

Comment: So use what works for you. `python forward.py -u <server_username> -r <router_ip:port> <server_name>`

Comment: Ok, that gives me `No authentication methods available` for the <server_name>. No input appears for the password. Any idea?

Comment: Add `-P` to get prompted for a password

Comment: Thanks and sorry for keep bugging you. I've reached the point where I see `Connecting to ssh host <server_name>:22 ...
Now forwarding port 22 to <rotuer_ip>:<port> ...` Am I supposed to see something after this? I haven't really changed the script yet.

Comment: Now to test is all this is feasible, put that to a background (adding `&` at the end) or open a new terminal and there do `ssh -P 22 router_username@127.0.0.1` - Though I've never told you to use `-p 22`. In general, you should not forward port 22. That can work only if you have no SSH server running locally, which would conflict. That's why I wrote `-p random_port`. Or do not use `-p` at all and let the script auto-assign a free port.

Comment: If I want to run a command in a router called `show ?` (lists all possible show commands), can I add that to the srcript and print the result out?

Comment: `ssh -P 22 router_username@127.0.0.1 show ?`