# Executing command from remote server into another remote server using Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I am trying to connect to a specific central server that has configured passwordless connection to all other servers, the server I am currently on has no access to the ones I want to run commands. So I am trying to connect to central server and from there do `ssh` into other servers I need to run commands. When I run this after I execute `ssh` command program gets frozen and does not allow to execute commands into final remote server. In this case let's say I want to run `ifconfig` on final server 'host.name'.

```
def get_host_info_linux(self,host,db_engine):
    #Create ssh client from paramiko library
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()

    try:
        # Connect to remote host
        #logger.info(username_pass)
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        client.connect(hostname='tunel host name', username=f'{db_engine}')
        #this command is to do ssh into the server I want to execute commands
        ssh_cmd = f'ssh {host.name}'

        ssh_std = client.exec_command(ssh_cmd)
        if (ssh_std[2].readlines() == []):+

            logger.debug(ssh_std[1].readlines()[0])

        else:
            logger.error(ssh_std[2].readlines())

      client.exe_command('ifconfig')

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e)
    finally:
        client.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In general to execute commands on server to which you can connect only via another SSH server, you should use port forwarding:
  [Nested SSH using Python Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35304525/850848)
- But if I understood correctly, you do not want to authenticate from the local machine, as you have the authentication set up from the jump host *(do you have a private key stored on the jump host?)* In that case, you want this:
  [Execute (sub)commands in secondary shell/command on SSH server in Python Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58452390/850848). Or you can bring the key from the jump host to the local machine. See [Nested SSH with RSA key file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63529027/850848).
- Though instead of feeding the commands to `ssh` via a redirected input, you might also use `ssh` command line as a more standardized interface:

  ```
  ssh destination command
  ```