# Keep alive mechanism for ssh over ssh in Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, tunnel

I'm using Paramiko interactive shell (`invoke_shell()` method) for opening session between my local host and remote host and sending commands to it.
Sometimes I need to open from my remote host an ssh connection to another remote host (this is like a bridge or SSH via SSH from local host to remote_host_2 via remote_host_1).

For better understanding this is a picture how it should behave:

```
| local host |  -(1)->    | remote host |  -(2)->   | destination host |
```

**1:** is open using `invoke_shell()` `paramiko` method so it will create some `paramiko.Channel` obj.
**2:** is open using Linux command i.e. `ssh remote_user@remote_ip`

This is done this way because sometimes I have no direct connection to `destination host` and in case you are opening it via `remote host` then user decision should be made (entering another `password`, answering `yes/no` on some questions etc..)

Now my question is regarding keeping my connection alive.
I read on `keep_alive` mechanism that `paramiko` has but it doesn't do what I want because `paramiko` knows my connection ends in `remote_host` and not in `destination host` so in case `destination host` is dead I will not receive any notification regarding it and commands execution will fail.

The only solution that came to my mind is sending empty command on this channel (`\n`) and trying to read the output from the channel before executing the desirable command on it. but this means that I can affect my channel on one hand and my command execution time is now twice longer.

Now my question is, is there another way to perform this connection so this **keep alive** mechanism will work?

p.s. I read that there exists some `ServerAliveInterval=30` flag that can help me to keep my `ssh` interactive connection alive but I don't understand how can I use it to validate it doesn't became dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is to implement the jump using port forwarding.
See [Connecting to a server via another server using Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57210100/850848)

Then you will have a complete control over both connections and you will be able to use native Paramiko features to keep the connection alive and to check its status.