# Port forwarding and the open SFTP using Python Paramiko

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko, portforwarding, ssh-tunnel

I have executed commands on server using ssh. Now I have to do another ssh to different IP while keeping old ssh active.

This new IP is port forward which will then used to do SFTP.

Issue I am facing is both ssh connections are on same port so not able to do second ssh.
Which is failing the SFTP.

Any support for same will be helpful.

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(ip, username=username, password=password, port=22)
time.sleep(3)
#Invoke shell to open multiple channel with in one SSH
chan = ssh.invoke_shell()
chan.send(ip1+'\n')
time.sleep(5)
chan.send(pass1+'\n')
time.sleep(10)

chan.send("ssh "+ip2+'\n')

time.sleep(10)
chan.send(pass2+'\n')
time.sleep(5)
#Execute command
chan.send(cmd)

#connect to another ip to do sftp
ssh1 = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh1.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect("127.0.0.4", username=usr2, password=pass2, port=22)
sftp=ssh.open_sftp()
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like misunderstanding. Your code does not do any port forwarding.

For the correct code, see [Nested SSH using Python Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35304525/850848#36096801).

If you need SFTP, not shell, just do:

```
jhost.open_sftp()
```

instead of

```
jhost.exec_command(command)
```

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not use `AutoAddPolicy` – You are losing a protection against [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) by doing so. For a correct solution, see [Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883)*.