# SSH from shell terminal to another server & execute commands using python paramiko

Tags: python, paramiko

```
import time
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect('x.x.x.x',22, username='root', password='12345')
ssh_stdin ,ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command('ssh -tt root@y.y.y.y')
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command('test@123')
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command('!pwd')
```

This is the code i want to run i want to login to shell terminal of x.x.x.x server & ssh to server y.y.y.y & excute several commands. please help me on this

Comment: Actually this one -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35304525/nested-ssh-using-python-paramiko solved my problem to certain extent. But i'm stuck now rsa key passing .it say no such file

Answer (score 0):

Try `sshpass` package.
The problem looks like that after you execute the first command, it is expecting the password, but the command is not returned to the client.

You can try installing `sshpass` first into x.x.x.x, and then use it like this:

```
sshpass -p 'YourPassword' ssh user@y.y.y.y
```

to login to y.y.y.y.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for  this. Anyway after login to 2nd device , is it possible execute commands using ssh.exec_command. it has a different shell interface commands are little different i want to get the output of these commands to python ouput