# Two step SSH local port forwarding using sshtunnel package

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, portforwarding, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to open a bi-directional tunnel between host1 and host3 with host2 in the middle.

```
host1 <--> host2 <--> host3
```

Here is the (blocking) bash command I am running on host1 to forward port 51672.

```
ssh -g -L 51672:host2:51672 host2_username@host2 \'/tmp/sshpass -p host3_pass ssh -g -L 51672:host3:51672 host3_username@host3 \'\'"while true; do : ; sleep 5; done"\'\'\'
```

I have a script running on `host3` listening to port 51672. When I create a TCP socket on `host1` and connect to `host2:51672`, I can communicate with the script on host3 through that socket.

In the next step, I am trying to port this into python and use the `sshtunnel` package. I am a little bit confused which option in [here](https://pypi.org/project/sshtunnel/) is equivalent to my scenario.

Here is my first attempt:

```
import paramiko
import sshtunnel

with sshtunnel.open_tunnel(
        ssh_address_or_host=(host2, 22),
        ssh_username=host2_username,
        ssh_password=host2_pass,
        local_bind_address=('0.0.0.0', 51672),
        remote_bind_address=(host3, 22),
        block_on_close=False
) as tunnel1:
    log.info('Tunnel to host2 is established.')
    with sshtunnel.open_tunnel(
            ssh_address_or_host=('localhost', tunnel1.local_bind_port),
            ssh_username=host3_username,
            ssh_password=host3_password,
            remote_bind_address=(host3, 51672),
            block_on_close=False
    ) as tunnel2:
        log.info('Tunnel to host3 is established.')
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
```

I can confirm that the tunnel is open from host1 to host2, because the following command returns 0 on host1.

```
nc -z localhost 51672
```

However, the tunnel between host2 and host3 seems to be not working.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to tunnel SSH. Then you tunnel your custom port.

Simpler to grasp approach (although not optimal) is:

- Open direct SSH connection to `host2`.
- Forward a local `host1:A` port via `host2` connection to `host3:22`
- Open SSH connection to `host3` using the the forwarded port `host1:A`.
- Forward another local `host1:B` port via `host3` to `host3:51672`.
- Connect to `host1:B` to get to `host3:51672`.

But you actually do not need to do the first physical port forwarding, you can use the `sock` approach as seen for example in [Nested SSH using Python Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35304525/850848).

*(I believe that even your original `ssh` approach is unnecessarily complicated, with its two forwardings)*