# Using pysftp to connect via jump server

Tags: python, ssh, pysftp

I am trying to upload a file to my home network via pysftp. My local device is connected via WireGuard to a VPS.

I can use `ssh` jumps to connect to the local device with

```
ssh -J user@VPS user@localdevice
```

Is there any way to do the same with pysftp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's probably possible to connect via jump servers using pysftp too, it's too high-level library to such technical task. And pysftp also seems to be a dead and abandoned project. See [pysftp vs. Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48434941/850848).

Use Paramiko directly (pysftp is just a wrapper on top of Paramiko). See
[Nested SSH using Python Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35304525/850848)

Answer (score -2):

Something like this

```
import pysftp

with pysftp.Connection('hostname', username='me', password='secret') as sftp:

    with sftp.cd('/allcode'):           # temporarily chdir to allcode
        sftp.put('/pycode/filename')    # upload file to allcode/pycode on remote
        sftp.get('remote_file')         # get a remote file
```

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_network_programming/python_sftp.htm

Comment: This allows me to connect to the VPS. But how do I enter the target for the jump?