# connection to ssh via Python

Tags: python, shell, ssh

I want to connect via ssh using python. I've tried this command:
os.system("cmd /k root@ip)
and it worked well. the problem is that after this a password is required and it is not clear to me which command shall I use.
Furthermore I noticed that the os.system command stay "alive" and doesn't allow the code to go on the next step until the shell is not closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using [paramiko](https://www.paramiko.org/)?

```py
import paramiko

ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client .connect(server, username=username, password=password)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command(command)
```

Comment: Ciao, 
I've exstablish an SSH connection using the following code:

> session = myconn.connect(SIM_IP, username =USER_SIM, password=PSW_SIM)
> stdin, stdout, stderr = myconn.exec_command(prova_comando)
> lines=stdout.readlines() print(lines)

now I want from this SSH, connect to another SSH which need the password as the previous one.
How can I do this?
Thanks

Comment: @Inuyasha84 this should be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35304525/nested-ssh-using-python-paramiko

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pexpect`'s `pxssh` module to connect to ssh and run command:

```
from pexpect import pxssh
import getpass
try:
    ssh_cmd = pxssh.pxssh()
    hostname = raw_input('hostname: ')
    username = raw_input('username: ')
    password = getpass.getpass('password: ')
    ssh_cmd.login(hostname, username, password)
    ssh_cmd.sendline('df -hT')   # run a command(you can specify any command here)
    ssh_cmd.prompt()             # match the prompt
    print(ssh_cmd.before)        # print everything before the prompt
    ssh_cmd.logout()
except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh as e:
    print("SSH login Failed")
    print(e)
```

For more details you can refer `pxssh` [documentation](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pxssh.html).