# Paramiko equivalent of OpenSSH ssh -J switch

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I am trying to translate this `ssh` this command to Python using the `paramiko` library.

```bash
sshpass -p SomePassword ssh -J specificSshHost admin@11.0.0.0 \ 
    -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa \ 
    -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 \ 
    -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no"
```

Where `specificSshHost` points to this file in `.ssh/config` as follows

```
Host specificSshHost
  User admin
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mySpecificRsaKey
```

What I have so far

```py
import paramiko
import os
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.load_host_keys("/home/name/.ssh/mySpecificRsaKey")
user = 'admin'
pswd = 'SomePassword'
ssh_keypath = ".ssh/mySpecificSshHost"
REMOTE_SERVER_IP = "11.0.0.0"
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname=str(REMOTE_SERVER_IP), username=user,
               key_filename=ssh_keypath)
```

This is what I find in the `paramiko` log file

```
INFO:paramiko.hostkeys:Not enough fields found in known_hosts in line 26 ('xPuIyxnS2aQoUvDVyCtJEJ47P6nH8su/bDGj6hrS1GBOFYLrCu4LBQ==')
INFO:paramiko.hostkeys:Unable to handle key of type RSA
```

I have read that `paramiko` supports the `rsa` and also those algorithms, so I do not understand why the `connect` command is just hanging there. The error trace triggered by a `keyboardInterrupt` is

```
  File "/tmp/ipykernel_202149/1488139442.py", line 36, in <module>
    client.connect(hostname=str(REMOTE_SERVER_IP), username =str(user),

  File "/home/david/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 358, in connect
    retry_on_signal(lambda: sock.connect(addr))

  File "/home/david/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paramiko/util.py", line 279, in retry_on_signal
    return function()

  File "/home/david/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 358, in <lambda>
    retry_on_signal(lambda: sock.connect(addr))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`-J` switch of OpenSSH `ssh`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#J) is for *jump host*. It has nothing to do with any *key*.

For implementing a jump host in Paramiko, see:
[Nested SSH using Python Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35304525/850848)

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not use `AutoAddPolicy` this way – You are losing a protection against [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) by doing so. For a correct solution, see [Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883)*.