# Running ftplib code on remote server with Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, ftplib

I need to execute the below commands in the order

Step 1 (from server1): `ssh server2`

Step 2 (from server2): `ftp server3`

How can I do the same?

```
import paramiko
import ftplib
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.connect(server2)
(stdin, stdout, stderr) = client.exec_command('ftp_server = ftplib.FTP(server3, user, pass) ; ftp_server.encoding = "utf-8" ; ftp_server.cwd("xx/yy") ; file=open("aa.png", "rb") ; ftp_server.storbinary(f"STOR {"aa.png"}", file)')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SSHClient.exec_command` maps to "exec" channel of the SSH server. The "exec" channel typically runs shell commands. While you are trying to run Python code. Either use the `exec_command` to run `ftp`. Or run `python` with your code (if the server has `python`).

Though the native Python solution would be to forward the local ports and run the Python FTP code locally to against the forwarded ports. Like here:
[Nested SSH using Python Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35304525/850848)
Except that you will use nesting FTP, not SSH. But port forwarding FTP is more difficult, as you need to forward even the data ports.