Second .connect with paramiko (ssh)
Form the main Linux OS (connected, working) I would like to run another ".connect".
Here is the code:
import paramiko
hostname =  "hostaname"
ip =        "1111.111.11.11"
username =  "user"
password =  "pass"
    
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname=hostname,username=username, password=password)

Now from the main I want to accesses another localhost:
hostname =  "localhost"
ip =        "222.222.2.2"
username =  "root"
password =  "root"
ssh.connect(hostname=hostname,username=username, password=password)

I get the following error:
NoValidConnectionsError: [Errno None] Unable to connect to port 22 on 222.222.2.2 or ::1

UPD: I found my answer in the following question:
Nested SSH using Python Paramiko

UPD: I found my answer in the following question: Nested SSH using Python Paramiko
Here is my full code and solution:
import paramiko
ip1_hostname =  "host-name-2024"

ip1 =      "1111.111.11.11"
ip2 =      "222.222.2.2"

ip1_username =  "username"
ip1_password =  "password"

root_user =     "root"
root_password = "root"

ip1_machine = paramiko.SSHClient()
ip1_machine.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ip1_machine.connect(hostname=ip1_hostname,username=ip1_username, password=ip1_password)

std_in, std_out, std_err = ip1_machine.exec_command('ls')
print(f"{std_out.read().decode().split()}")

# based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35304525/nested-ssh-using-python-paramiko
ip1_transport = ip1_machine.get_transport()
dest_addr = (ip2, 22)     # "222.222.2.2"
local_addr = (ip1, 22)   # "1111.111.11.11"
ip2_channel = ip1_transport.open_channel("direct-tcpip", dest_addr, local_addr)

ip2 = paramiko.SSHClient()
ip2.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ip2.connect(ip2, username=root_user, password=root_password, sock=ip2_channel)
std_in, std_out, std_err = ip2.exec_command('ls')
print(f"{std_out.read().decode().split()}")

