# Correctly using banner_timeout in paramiko

Tags: python, server, client, paramiko

I'm trying to have many clients send files to a server all at once (or as fast as possible) but the  server is getting too many requests at once as in the question [Paramiko: Error reading SSH protocol banner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25609153/paramiko-error-reading-ssh-protocol-banner).  I've tried adding a banner_timeout so that the clients will try a little longer to connect to server, however, I'm thrown an error: 
`TypeError: connect() got an unexpected keyword arguement 'banner_timeout'`

```
import paramiko, os, time
host_IP='192.168.1.1'
port=22
transport=paramiko.Transport((host_IP,port))
transport.connect(username='username', password='password', banner_timeout=60)
sftp=paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
```

Perhaps I'm using the transport incorrectly?

Comment: `paramiko.Transport.connect` doesn't take `banner_timeout` argument.

Comment: Try using `ssh=paramiko.SSHClient() ; ssh.connect(host, username = 'username', password = 'password', timeout = 60)`

Comment: @boardrider Thanks!  This allowed me to use the banner timeout and then open an sftp connection.  Unfortunately, using banner_timeout option did not solve my underlying problem.

Comment: If you're unable to solve your `banner_timeout,` create a new SO question  - and describe there what you tried, including a [mcve].

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

You can set it like `transport.banner_timeout = 60` *before* connecting.